# Why can I omit parenthesis around an anonymous function in an IIFE when prefixing it with a unary operator?

Tags: javascript

Why do I not need to wrap the anonymous function in an Immediately-invoked Function Expression (IIFE) in parenthesis when using a unary operator such as `+` or `-`?

```js
// No parenthesis around anonymous function necessary
+function() {

}();
```

```
// Parenthesis around function are necessary
(function() {

})();
```

Functionally they should be equivalent?

Comment: Because `(` is an opening parenthesis and `+` is not an opening parenthesis?

Comment: `+` is a unary operator in JS. This forces the following `function` to be parsed in an expression context (as an anonymous function), such that the call can be applied to it without wrapping the function in parenthesis. Due to the operator precedence here, this parses as `+(function(){}())` rather than `(+function(){})()` which would throw an error. I love it (for the purposes of code golfing) :)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "different char". This works only because `+` is a unary operator. Of course it will also work with other unary operators, say `-`, so long as they don't raise an error when applied to whatever your function returns (`undefined` in this case).

Comment: I mistakenly said "different char" out of ignorance. I wasn't aware it had to be a unary operator, which now makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, I think your edits are sound. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at how this looks from the perspective of a parser. First, why does

```js
function(){}();
```

not work? Simple: The parser expects a *statement*:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`

Typically so-called *predictive parsers* look at one token of lookahead. That is, the parser is expecting a statement, sees `function`, and then expects a function statement. The `function` keyword needs to then be followed by a name, but there is no name, so this is a syntax error. Basically you're clashing with the function definition special syntax here, and the function definition syntax takes precedence over anonymous functions for a predictive parser which just looks at a single token.

Now let's look at the parenthesized variant:

```js
(function(){})();
```

The parser first sees the parentheses. Inside the parentheses, it expects an *expression*. Anonymous functions are expressions, so when the parser sees the `function` keyword, it correctly expects and then subsequently parses the anonymous function. You're effectively using the parentheses here to force the parser to see `function(){}` as an expression. That expression is part of a larger call expression, which makes up a statement.

Now, why does

```js
+function(){}();
```

work? The predictive parser sees the unary operator, which must be followed by an expression. So it now expects an expression and will parse `function(){}` as an anonymous function - which is an expression - and a subsequent call. [Function calls have higher precedence than unary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence), so this will end up as `+(function(){}());` - the unary operator is only applied to the result of the IIFE, thus not affecting the behavior at all since this is in a statement and the value is discarded anyways; `+undefined` is `NaN` but that doesn't matter.

Since all unary operators have the same precedence, other unary operators work just as well so long as they don't throw errors if they can't deal with the value of your IIFE (for instance`++function(){console.log("hi")}();` will throw a `ReferenceError`). A particularly funny example is `void function(){}();`, which is completely fine.

In practice, typically using a statement of the form `<unary operator>function(){}();` won't be useful; I can at best imagine it being somewhat useful with `await`. Either way I wouldn't use this "trick" to save myself one parenthesis in serious code; it raises eyebrows for no reason by introducing unnecessary operations for syntactical reasons.

---

For code golfing purposes, this is definitely a neat trick to shave off a byte from IIFEs (though arrow functions will usually be shorter) :)